# infoWindow and center on click outside map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have been playing around with Google Maps, and would like to center on a marker and open the appropriate infoWindow when I click on an element outside the map.
For example I have;

```
<div id="map"></div>
Store A
Opening Hours: 10-10

Store B
Opening Hours: 10-4

Store C
Opening Hours: 9-9

Store D.
Opening Hours: 8-9
```

I would like it to work, when I click on one of the stores in the list (outside of the map), it call the appropriate marker, centres on it and opens the attached infoWindow.
The infoWindow is working on marker click.

```js
function initMap() {
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
zoom: 11,
center: {
lat: -33.800426,
lng: 142.038494
}
  });
  setMarkers(map);
}

// Data for the markers consisting of a name, a LatLng and a zIndex for     the
// order in which these markers should display on top of each other.

var stores = [
          ['A', -33.771624, 142.888128, 1],
          ['B', -33.843956, 142.994875, 2],
          ['C', -33.818086, 142.995699, 3],
          ['C', -33.812697, 143.229200, 4],
          ];

function setMarkers(map) {
  // Adds markers to the map.
  for (var i = 0; i < stores.length; ++i) {
    var store = stores[i];
    const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: {
        lat: store[1],
        lng: store[2]
      },
      map: map,
      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
      title: store[0],
      zIndex: store[3],
    });
    attachStoreTitle(marker);
  }
}

// Attaches an info window to a marker with the provided message. When         the
// marker is clicked, the info window will open with message.
function attachStoreTitle(marker) {
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: marker.title
});
marker.addListener('click', function() {
infowindow.open(marker.get('map'), marker);
});
}
initMap()
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: You need to attach an event listener (using jQuery or js) to the items you wish to trigger the event from and some way to link the marker to the element. You could achieve this with a marker ID in a data attribute on the element.

Comment: @PaulThomasGC how would I do this. I've edited the code above to include the html. I'm assuming the 'Store A' text would be <h3 data-id="marker1">Store A</h3>
How do I then call the right marker to center on and open the infoWindow.

Comment: @Matthew any chance you can set it up as a codepen or js fiddle? Are you using jQuery?

Comment: @PaulThomasGC https://jsfiddle.net/Scud89/00e58pba/#&togetherjs=5oJpMae6d9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Completed fiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/00e58pba/8/

Attach event listener to markers and then open correct infoWindow -

```
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
  return function() {

    // Close all other infoboxes
    for (var j = 0; j < markers.length; j++) {
      markers[j].infobox.close(map);
    }

    // Open correct info box
    markers[i].infobox.open(map, markers[i]);
  }
})(marker, i));
```

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood what you're asking, I think you should be able to do this:

```js
marker.addListener('click', function() {
  infowindow.open(marker.get('map'), marker);
  marker.get('map').setCenter(this.getPosition());
});
```